# How to create route for dummy interface

Tags: linux, static-routes

I have two linux servers 172.20.140.10 and 172.20.140.11 in same network. 172.20.140.10 is used for simulating the devices and 172.20.140.11 is my Collector.
In  172.20.140.10 I have created 2000 Virtual IP's (Sample command I used for creating the Virtual IP is ifconfig dummy0:1 10.0.0.1 ) .Range of Virtual IP's I created 10.0.0.1-250,10.0.1.1-250,10.0.2.1-250 and so on)

The Virtual IP's i created in .10 are not reachable .10 box.
I want to know how to create the Route between them.
Also how to open the SNMP and Telnet port between them

Comment: I have created route to this IP's and I am able to Ping and telnet to this IP's. But I ma not able to do snmpwalk to the virtual IP's

Comment: Interesting question. I am looking for an answer, as well.